# React Native: How to determine if component is in the view port

Tags: react-native

That's said there's a long ScrollView with lots of contents, and there's another component at the bottom of the page. I'm trying to lazy-rendering the bottom component when user scroll down enough. Is there any library has implemented this?

(I'm aware of ListView's onEndReached, but not quite sure if that helpful for this case.)

Appreciate if anyone could guide me a direction.

Comment: i am not full clear about your lazy rendering but implementing the scrollview to specific components can only possess characteristics of scrollable with selected components, and the last or bottom component remains static without enclosing it with scrollview tag.

Comment: For example, a long article component with a comment component at the bottom. If the user just skim through articles and not scroll at all, no need to fetch the comments and render it. It would be efficient only to fetch comments when user scroll close to the bottom.

Comment: any reason for not using ListView component of react-native ?

Answer (score 3):

I create a simple lib for this:

https://github.com/chunghe/react-native-defer-renderer

basically you could get scroll position from the `onScroll` event of the `ScrollView` (`e.nativeEvent.contentOffset`), pass the scroll position to the child component. Then in the child component, you could get the distance from top from `onLayout` event (`e.nativeEvent.layout.y`). 
That's pretty much all the tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the end of the ScrollView?

ScrollViews do this by default:

> **removeClippedSubviews** bool
>
> Experimental: When true, offscreen child views (whose overflow value is hidden) are removed from their native backing superview when offscreen. This can improve scrolling performance on long lists. The default value is true.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#removeclippedsubviews

Comment: That's a good one! I try this a bit, but it seems the components still get rendered, the requests in `ComponentDidMount` still be called.